# In Scala, why is NaN not being picked up by pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, ieee-754, nan

My method is as follows

```
  def myMethod(myDouble: Double): Double = myDouble match {
    case Double.NaN => ...
    case _ => ...
  }
```

The IntelliJ debugger is showing NaN but this is not being picked up in my pattern matching. Are there possible cases I am omitting

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is a general rule how 64-bit floating point numbers are compared according to IEEE 754 (not Scala or even Java related, see [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)):

```
double n1 = Double.NaN;
double n2 = Double.NaN;
System.out.println(n1 == n2);     //false
```

The idea is that `NaN` is a marker value for *unknown* or *indeterminate*. Comparing two unknown values should always yields `false` as they are well... unknown.

---

If you want to use pattern matching with `NaN`, try this:

```
myDouble match {
    case x if x.isNaN => ...
    case _ => ...
}
```

But I think pattern matching will use strict double comparison so be careful with this construct.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `NaN != NaN` in many (if not all) programming languages that expose this value to the programmer.

Comment: Note that if most numbers are not NaN, `.isNaN` is only about half as fast as `java.lang.Double.isNaN`, so the latter should be preferred in tight loops.  (The match is as fast as an if statement.)  For clarity (i.e. everywhere except tight performance-critical loops), the `.isNaN` form is probably best.

Answer (score 13):

You can write an extractor (updated according to bse's comment):

```
object NaN {
  def unapply(d:Double) = d.isNaN
}


0.0/0.0 match {
  case NaN() => println("NaN")
  case x => println("boring " + x)
}
//--> NaN
```

Comment: The extractor can be even simpler: `object NaN { def unapply(d:Double) = d.isNaN }`. It can be used like this: `0.0/0.0 match { case NaN() => print("NaN") }`

Answer (score 5):

Tomasz is correct. You should use `isNaN` instead.

```
scala> Double.NaN.isNaN
res0: Boolean = true
```